# Error al no ingresar dato en inicio de sesión

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Al no ingresar datos en el usuario se cierra la aplicación
el código .java lo deja abajo

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    //comprobar si el usuario no existe en la base de datos
    if (dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).exists()) {

        //Informacion usuario

        mDialog.dismiss();
        Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(Usuario.class);
        if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
            {
                Intent homeintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inicio.class);
                Common.currentUsuario = usuario;
                startActivity(homeintent);
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Constraseña incorrecta !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario no registrado en base de dato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

El error es

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                          at
>   shop.easy.app.x.com.x.MainActivity$3$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:98)
>
> específicamente esta parte del codigo .java
>
> ```
>  if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
> ```

Comment: Existes un componente en android studio llamado logcat. Intenta ejecutar la aplicacion y cuando de el error, muestranos lo que muestra el logcat sino no sera dificil ayudarte.

Comment: Al parecer no validas campos vacíos, por eso te arroja el error, solo validas que el usuario exista ...

Comment: @Einer lo siento recién me di cuenta, gracias por avisar, ya subí el logcat

Comment: `dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(Usuario.class)`esta retornando null. Verifica que los datos estes recibiendo los datos correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con :

```
    if (edtPassword.getText().toString() != null){

         if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString()) != null) { 
       //Informacion usuario

        mDialog.dismiss();
        Usuario usuario = dataSnapshot.child(edtPhone.getText().toString()).getValue(Usuario.class);
        if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {
            {
                Intent homeintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Inicio.class);
                Common.currentUsuario = usuario;
                startActivity(homeintent);
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Constraseña incorrecta !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        mDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Usuario no registrado en base de dato", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    }
else {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No se ha recibido datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Así validas que tu `editText` no este vació o mejor dicho que ha recibido datos.

Comment: habría que definir el usuario en el segundo if ?                                          ademas tengo un  error java.lang.string por el >0

Comment: Si, el primero validas que sean distinto de null nada mas, envuelve todo el proceso el if.., he editado la respuesta @Neil

Comment: me sigue dando el error :c en el  if (usuario.getContraseña().equals(edtPassword.getText().toString())) {  @Ashley G.

Comment: te sigue dando el mismo error ? o es otro diferente @Neil

Comment: el mismo error, edite el código que me diste ya que no existe usuario en el segundo if y me generaba un error fue el único cambio que realice @ Ashley G.

Comment: puedes realizar la misma condición que el primer if distinto a null .. @Neil

Comment: Utiliza el código de Ashley englobando los dos campos en el primer `if`:
`if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString()) &&  !TextUtils.isEmpty(edtPassword.getText().toString()))`

Comment: Asi es puedes tambien realizarlo como dice @Israel